# Error while using suspend with DAO methods

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I'm getting a compilation error that I have described below. I have tried different solution provided on similar question like mine but neither of them worked for me.

Please help me with this.

The errors I'm getting:-

(1)

```
error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> continuation);
```

(2)

```
error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
public abstract java.lang.Object addTransaction(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

(3)

```
error: Not sure how to handle delete method's return type. Currently the supported 
return types are void, int or Int.
public abstract java.lang.Object deleteTransaction(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

(4)

```
error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a 
collection/array of it.
kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> continuation);
```

(5)

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

This is a compilation error that I am getting while building:-

[image]

`DAO class`:

```
package com.tallileo.myapplication.TransactionDatabase

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.*

 @Dao
 interface TransactionDao {
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
   suspend fun addTransaction(transaction:Transaction)

   @Delete
   suspend fun deleteTransaction(transaction:Transaction)

   @Query("SELECT * FROM transactions ORDER BY id DESC")
   fun getAllTransaction():LiveData<List<Transaction>>
}
```

`Entity Class`:

```
package com.tallileo.myapplication.TransactionDatabase

import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "transactions")
data class Transaction(
   val transactionType:String,
   val amountType:String,
   val name:String,
   val amount:String,
   val accountTo:String,
   val accountFrom:String,
   val categoryType:String,
   val currency:String,
   var additionalNote:String=""
 ) {
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   var id:Int=0
 }
```

`Database Class`:

```
package com.tallileo.myapplication.TransactionDatabase

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [Transaction::class], version = 1, exportSchema = true)
abstract class TransactionDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun transactDao():TransactionDao

    companion object {
        // Singleton prevents multiple instances of database opening at the
        // same time.
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: TransactionDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): TransactionDatabase {
            // if the INSTANCE is not null, then return it,
            // if it is, then create the database
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    TransactionDatabase::class.java,
                    "TransactionDatabase"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                // return instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tallileo.myapplication"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    def roomVersion = "2.3.0"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //Lottie Animation
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.0'

    //room components
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-common:2.3.0'
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")
}
```

Kotlin version is `1.6.0`. Also when I remove suspend from all the methods in the DAO, then there is no compilation error.

Comment: Very strange, I took all your files that you posted and project builds fine for me, Have you tried invalidating caches and restarting android studio?

Comment: Yes, I have tried invalidating and restarting. But it seems it is problem with android studio. I think I have to reinstall it.

Comment: @SarthakKumar try adding this to your dependencies: `implementation "androidx.room:room-coroutines:$roomVersion"`

Comment: Earlier, I was using this dependency but it didn't work for me. In the documentation the dependency used for using coroutines with room is: implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion"). So I removed the other depency and added this one.

Comment: Which Android Studio version do you have installed?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue! I updated to Kotlin 1.6.0 and the latest Android Studio and I'm also getting these errors. My code compiled fine before. The only thing that "fixes" it is removing the `suspend` keyword, but I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

All of your room versions should be the same.  You have expressly called out `common` differently than the rest.  Why not let `common` just come in transitivley?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem as well, updating my room_version from `'2.3.0'` to `'2.4.0-beta02'` fixed it!